# unable to get content-length header working under rails 4.1+puma

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rack, content-length, puma

Setup is: Puma: 2.9.1
Rails: 4.1.5
Rack: 1.5.2

As per documentation i tried to get ContentLength header working by adding fallowing to my application.rb

```
config.middleware.use Rack::ContentLength
```

Unfortunately response was still chunked. After some investingation i found following condition in Rack::ContentLength class:

```
  if !STATUS_WITH_NO_ENTITY_BODY.include?(status.to_i) &&
     !headers['Content-Length'] &&
     !headers['Transfer-Encoding'] &&
     body.respond_to?(:to_ary)
```

body.respond_to?(:to_ary) is only one which yields false. At that context body is instance of Rack::BodyProxy in which responds_to? is overriden:

```
def respond_to?(*args)
  return false if args.first.to_s =~ /^to_ary$/
  super or @body.respond_to?(*args)
end
```

I am really confused here. Removing body.respond_to?(:to_ary) resolves issue, but i dont feel safe just removing chunks of code from rack lib. Any help getting content-length header working are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this, by chance? I just posted a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112728/when-does-rails-respond-with-transfer-encoding-vs-content-length