# NSURLCache does not work when response header value for transfer-encoding is chunked

Tags: ios, swift, caching, ios8, nsurlcache

I found an issue with (possibly) `NSURLCache` today while inspecting request and response headers in Charles Proxy. The issue is a little perplexing, but I'm able to repro it consistently:

In a nutshell, the issue has to do with caching of `NSURLRequest`s using iOS's native `NSURLCache` with the default policy. It turns out that the request is not cached whenever the response has the header `transfer-encoding: chunked`. But if the response header is `content-length: xxx` instead, caching works fine. Specifically, it seems that when the response is chunked, NSURLCache doesn't save the eTag and also neglects appending the `if-none-match` header to subsequent requests to the same url, and consequently, caching fails (as it should), i.e. a 200 is returned instead of a 304.

I'm testing on the iOS8.2 simulator. Even if you don't have a solution, I'd love to hear if you've experienced the same issue. I've found at least [one similar report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248707/nsurlcache-inconsistent-behaviour#answer-26789163)), and here's a [related thread posted by my back-end engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112728/when-does-rails-respond-with-transfer-encoding-vs-content-length).

Comment: None, other than we are able to repro this bug with high certainty. For now, we're looking into always sending the JSON back with the content-length header. What's the nature of your problem?

Comment: Hi, our backend system cannot return content-length because the response is huge and it must be returned as chunks. So we need to find the way to cache chunked response or an official documentation saying that is impossible. Appreciate any advice.

Comment: Hi, check out my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20248707/nsurlcache-inconsistent-behaviour

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you manually add the response data to the cache. I've got an image loading class where I want to make sure everything is cached, so I do something like this:

```
- (void)getImageWithURL:(NSURL *)url onCompletion:(void (^)(UIImage *image, NSError *error))completion {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    UIImage *cachedImage = [self cachedImageForURLRequest:request];
    if (cachedImage) {
        NSLog(@"Got image from cache.");
        completion(cachedImage, nil);
        return;
    }

    [[[NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]] dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
        // Manually cache the response.
        NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSCachedURLResponse alloc] initWithResponse:response data:data userInfo:nil storagePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageAllowed];
        [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] storeCachedResponse:cachedResponse forRequest:request];
        NSLog(@"Got a fresh image.");
        completion([UIImage imageWithData:data], error);
    }] resume];
}

- (UIImage *)cachedImageForURLRequest:(NSURLRequest *)urlRequest {
    NSCachedURLResponse *cachedResponse = [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] cachedResponseForRequest:urlRequest];
    return [UIImage imageWithData:cachedResponse.data];
}
```