# Rails 5.1 Webrick includes Content-Length whereas Puma does not

Tags: ruby-on-rails, puma, webrick

Rails `5.1.4` Webrick includes `Content-Length` in the response header. Changing to Puma `3.10.0` causes the `Content-Length` to no longer appear. Is there a Puma setting to include the `Content-Length` property in the response header?

Comment: did you read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29112728/when-does-rails-respond-with-transfer-encoding-vs-content-length

Comment: I did see that post. I’m not not sure if Webrick always sends the Content-Length and Rails has to explicitly set Content-Length when using Puma. Right now I am not setting Content-Length yet Webrick correctly sets it.

Answer (score 1):

Use Rack::ContentLength middleware as suggested here: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/32585

Add this to your development.rb / production.rb

```
config.middleware.use(Rack::ContentLength)
```